# Chrome Extension to modify images that fail to load

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

There's a site that I go to, that has old pages that are useful, but the images have disappeared on their site. Fortunately for **me**, I happen to have a bunch of those images because, I kept copies of them. So, it's easy enough for me to look at those images one by one. But, here's what I want to do:

I want to write a Chrome extension that will somehow find any images that failed to load, and replace them with images that I will package up in my extension.

So, say for instance, if the original image was `http://broken.site/whatever1/whatever2/whatever3/missing.jpg` (and if it indeed is erroring), I'd like that to get replaced with `missing.jpg` that I have in my extension.

I *don't* want it to load *all* images from that site from the cache I'll provide, only ones that error. Is there an easy way to do this?

I can see how to get all the images with this:

```
imgs = document.getElementsByTagName("img")
```

`imgs[0].src` seems to give me the URL, and that's cool. But `imgs[0].complete`  says complete regardless of whether it successfully retrieved the image or not. Is there a way to figure out whether a particular image actually did load or not?

Comment: Hm. I thought of recommending `webRequest` API, but it's too late to redirect when the error occurs.

Comment: Nevermind, for server error responses it's possible. Writing an answer.

Comment: A word of advice, if you're new to Chrome extensions, _for the love of god(s)_ please read the [Overview page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview) in its entirety. It will preempt a lot of questions you may have.

Comment: Thanks Xan, Thanks Smilledge.. Unfortunately, I tried what you guys wrote, and I couldn't get it to work... No doubt due to my own lack of inexperience with chrome plugins. In any case, I did get what I needed working. It's at https://github.com/bnsh/chrome-pgm .. I guess I wouldn't mind criticism of the extension there.. But, it basically does what I need... Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

You can catch and redirect requests that server replied to with 404 using [`webRequest` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest).

This way, you can do it in a background script and won't need a content script to analyze the page with `document.getElementsByTagName("img")`, requests will be intercepted "in flight".

```
function isMissing(line) {
  return !!(line.match(/^[^ ]* 404/));
}

chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener(
  function(details) {
    if(isMissing(details.statusLine)) {
      var fixedURL;
      /* TODO: Assign fixedURL based on details.url */
      // If the image is in the extension, use
      //   chrome.runtime.getURL("filename.jpg")
      return {redirectUrl: fixedURL};
    }
  },
  {
    // Tailor this filter for your site
    urls: ["*://*.example.com/*"],
    types: ["image"]
  },
  ["blocking"]
);
```

You will need host permissions (e.g. `"*://*.example.com/*"`), `"webRequest"` and `"webRequestBlocking"`.

Answer (score 1):

I built the extension [Image Fallback](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/image-fallback/bdalekeapajlinfmggjofpajebfcdoke) which sounds very similar to what you are trying to achieve.

You can view the source code for the extension on [github](https://github.com/smilledge/chrome-image-fallback). I've added a couple of relevant snippets from this codebase below.

Here is the code from the background script that listens for images that have failed to load. It then sends a message to the content script with the image that needs to be replaced.

```
/**
 * Stores messages for each tab keyed by tabId
 *
 * These will be used if an image errors before the content script has loaded 
 */
var tabMessages = {};

/**
 * Listen to all responses for images
 * 
 * If the status code is 404 and the host have a fallback url configured notify the content script
 */
chrome.webRequest.onCompleted.addListener(function(e) {

  // Ignore responses if the status code was not a 404 or 500 
  if (!e.statusCode || (e.statusCode !== 404 && e.statusCode !== 500)) {
    return;
  }

  var message = {
    target: targetImage,
    fallback: fallbackUrl
  };

  // Send a message to the content script for this tab
  chrome.tabs.sendMessage(e.tabId, message, function(response) {
    if (typeof response === 'undefined') {
      // The content script probably hasn't loaded yet
      // Add fallback to the message queue for this tab
      // Instead the content script must request image replacements once it is loaded
      tabMessages[e.tabId].push(message);
    }
  });
}, {
  urls: ['<all_urls>'],
  types: ['image']
}, ['responseHeaders']);
```

This is the content script that listens for messages from the background script and then swaps out the image.

```
/**
 * Request any images that have errored before this script was loaded from the background script.
 */
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
  action: 'getImageFallbacks'
}, function(response) {
  if (!response || !response.length) {
    return;
  }

  response.forEach(function(replace) {

    // Replace the images with your fallback
    $('[src$="'+ replace.target +'"]').attr('src', replace.fallback);

  });
});

/**
 * Listen for image replacement requests sent from the background script
 */
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(replace, sender, sendResponse) {

  // Replace the images with your fallback
  $('[src$="'+ replace.target +'"]').attr('src', replace.fallback);

  // Send a response to the background script so it knows we have replaced this image
  sendResponse({
    success: true
  });
});
```

You will also need to following permission in your manifest.json:

```
"permissions": ["<all_urls>", "webRequest","webRequestBlocking", "tabs", "storage"]
```

Comment: Interesting spin, though if you compare it with my solution (untested!), I don't need a content script since I can redirect at the `webRequest` level.